# Can't add css class to element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add class to element.

```css
.html5-video-player {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(90deg) !important;

}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=p-_qed5LTTg">test</a>
```

I can't add CSS to element. I need to rotate in mobile devices. So I will later add bootstrap class `@media (max-width: 767.98px) {` to element after make it working.

[Here](https://codepen.io/codepenju/pen/GRMOWWr) is codepen.

I can't **directly** embed video in my website as I don't have space for that. I need it as link or link button. If `watch_popup` method don't work, I can also try bootstrap modal which has button, clicking on it will pop up embeded video. Rotating  that to 90 degree to full screen also acceptable. Or any other javascript/jQuery method out there to make it happen? I need the rotation(Full screen) in mobile devices only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the video content in `<iframe>`. Clicking `<button>` rotates `<iframe>` 90 degrees.

```js
function rotate(){
 document.getElementById("special-container").setAttribute("style", "display: inline !important");
  document.getElementById("camera_view").setAttribute("style","transform: rotate(90deg)");
}
```

```css
a{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a onclick="rotate()">Rotate</a>
    
    <div id="special-container" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="display: none;">
        <iframe id="camera_view" class="embed-responsive-item container well well-small span6"
            style="height: 720px; width: 1280px; background-color: #2e2e2e;"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=p-_qed5LTTg">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did I understand your problem correctly?

Comment: Thanks, you give it as embeded. I need it as a link/button

Comment: You misunderstood me. I can't embed video in my website. I need it as link like, `<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=p-_qed5LTTg">test</a>` or button like `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=p-_qed5LTTg">test</a>`. Or some way to popup the link button by bootstrap modal or other plugin with 90 degree rotation.

Comment: @user1607213 If you can't embed the video, then you misunderstand what control you have; you can't modify youtube's website(which you would be at if you followed a link) with your own CSS without a browser extension.

Comment: @Daedalus How about using bootstrap modal and rotate 90 degree in mobile devices.

Comment: I've developed a container that is initially hidden as you might think, but returns and becomes visible when clicked.

Comment: @user1607213 That would be an embed, which you just said you can't do.  If this modal is a `window.open()` created popup, see above.  It's a security issue, so that won't work.

Comment: @Daedalus But bootstrap modal is a link button and clicking that link button it pops up. So that can be considered.

Comment: @Sercan please give more info

Comment: @user1607213 Are you changing your rule that it can't be an embed?  Because a bootstrap modal is only possible if you are embedding the video into it. Moreso, if you are changing that rule, then this answer answers the question, even if it does not directly use the bootstrap modal.

Comment: @Daedalus I have space for a button only in my website. So modal have button. Eventhough it is embeded, it will only visible after clicking button. Right? Thats way its ok.

Comment: @Sercan Thanks for the code. Although it is rotating it don't go to full screen in mobile I think. Can you confirm? Any way I marked it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot class="html5-video-player" in thé link 'a'

Comment: Its a class of youtube popup, not in my code.